# How to create an observable based on a while loop?

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable, rxjs6

I am trying to create an Observable that continuously queries an outside service for updates, and if there is a new one, emits the update:

```
this._loop = new Rx.Observable<TDL.Result>(subscriber =>
{
    let shouldLoop = true;

    while (shouldLoop)
    {
        if (!this._client)
            throw new Error("This client is not initialised.");

        const update = this._lib.receiveSync(this._client, 5);

        if (!update)
            continue;

        if (update._ === "error")
            this.emit("error", update);
        else
            this.emit("update", update);

        subscriber.next(update);
    }

    // never gets here b/c of while loop, so subscribing to this Observable
    // causes everything to block

    // cancellation logic
    return () =>
    {
        shouldLoop = false;
        this._loop = null;
    };
}).pipe(RxOp.publish()) as Rx.ConnectableObservable<TDL.Result>;

this._loopSubscription = this._loop.connect();
```

However, the subscribe function is blocking, which means that my code halts when I call `connect()`. How do I rewrite this to make the subscription function non-blocking?

Comment: `subscribe` is only blocking as far as  your `new Observable(o => ...)` is blocking. However, looks like you could loop with something like `setTimeout` instead of `while`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @martin, the solution was pretty obvious. I don't know why I didn't think of this

```
this._loop = new Rx.Observable<TDL.Result>(subscriber =>
{
    let shouldLoop = true;

    process.nextTick(() =>
    {
        while (shouldLoop)
        {
            if (!this._client)
                throw new Error("This client is not initialised.");

            const update = this._lib.receiveSync(this._client, 5);

            if (!update)
                continue;

            if (update._ === "error")
                this.emit("error", update);
            else
                this.emit("update", update);

            subscriber.next(update);
        }
    });

    // cancellation logic
    return () =>
    {
        shouldLoop = false;
        this._loop = null;
    };
}).pipe(RxOp.publish()) as Rx.ConnectableObservable<TDL.Result>;
```